# How do I log from PHP to the Firefox "Server" filter in the Developer Tools?

Tags: php, firefox, logging

How do I print my debug logs so that they are correctly marked as "Server" from Firefox's console filters? Do I need to put them in the headers? Right now I echo a script tag that calls the 'console.log' function, but that doesn't look like the best way to log things. Expecially if on a PHP script that is supposed to return json data only.

[image: exaple]

Comment: You cannot write logs to the browser as part of the request response. You need some side channel. Typically this is done using a server side extension like xdebug in combination with a client side logic, an IDE or a browser plugin.

Comment: Then why is the server filter there? To troll me?

Comment: I assume this is a builtin client for above mentioned server side features. I suggest you take a look into the mozilla  documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Console_messages#Server) Firefox has built-in support for the [ChromeLogger](https://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger) protocol.